# Angular CDK Overlay flexibleConnectedTo doesn't connect to origin

Tags: angular-material, angular-cdk

I would like to connect an angular cdk overlay to a button in my toolbar.
That's what I got:

overlay-button.html:

```
<button mat-menu-item #overlayButton (click)="showOverlay()"> open </button>
```

overlay-button.component

```
export class OverlayButtonComponent {
  @ViewChild('overlayButton') private _button: ElementRef;

  constructor(private _overlay: OverlayService) {}

  showOverlay() {
    this._overlay.open(DisplayedComponent,this._button);
  }
}
```

overlay.service

```
export class OverlayService {
  constructor(private _overlay: Overlay) {}

  open(comp: ComponentType<any>, connectedTo:ElementRef) {
    const positionStrategy = this._overlay.position()
      .flexibleConnectedTo(connectedTo)
      .withPositions([{
        originX: 'start',
        originY: 'bottom',
        overlayX: 'start',
        overlayY: 'top',
      }]);

    const overlayRef = this._overlay.create({
      hasBackdrop: true,
      positionStrategy,
      scrollStrategy: this._overlay.scrollStrategies.reposition()
    });

    // Create ComponentPortal that can be attached to a PortalHost
    const filePreviewPortal = new ComponentPortal(comp);

    // Attach ComponentPortal to PortalHost
    overlayRef.attach(filePreviewPortal);

    overlayRef.backdropClick().subscribe(() => overlayRef.detach());
  }
}
```

The problem is that the overlay is always displayed in the top left corner of the Browser.
First i thought there is a problem with the viewChild, maybe the elementRef is undefined or something like that, but that is not the case. I tried every tutorial I found with similar code and nothing worked. Could the problem be anywhere else?

Here is an illustration of how it is:

[image: overlay problem]

Comment: Hey Yannick, I'm having the exact same problem and also confirmed is not because of an undefined/null ref.

Did you manage to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The reference you get from your `ViewChild` is not actually `ElementRef`. You can wrap the button to a `div` and then get `ViewChild` reference to that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @joonas comment, modify your viewChild Code to be

```
 @ViewChild('overlayButton', {read: ElementRef}) private _button: ElementRef;
```

forcing the viewChild to be read as an ElementRef, and thereby passed into the `flexibleConnectedTo()` call.